# What is the mule recommended method to invoke flows in mulesoft?

Tags: mule, lookup, dataweave, mulesoft

I want to understand the best way to invoke flows in mulesoft. Is it using lookup function in dataweave or using flow ref component?

Also, Is there any disadvantage using lookup function going forward? Current mule runtime is 3.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flow references with subflows when possible.
The lookup function will prevent you from previewing your DW expression at design time, it can only invoke flows not subflows and flows use more resources as compared to subflows.

I personally avoid lookup, I only use it when I have no other way.

Comment: adding to this, lookups are not testable(as per my current knowledge). So, under test driven development, it is better if lookups are avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that I would use when the lookup pattern applies. This mean when you have a big input like a CSV and while mapping it you want to do a lookup on thirdparty system with a field of each entry and you don't want to run out of memory. In this cases I would say the lookup pattern applies perfect.